# How to show seaborn plots in an Flutter App

Tags: python, python-3.x, flutter, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

is it possible to show a plot(Distplot,Heatmap etc.), created with seaborn, in a Flutter App.

-> The App should be capable of changing the plots data

I did't find anything towards this topic, so it could be an interesting conversation.

Thanks!

Comment: What about to export the plot in a format that you can insert in your Flutter app?

Comment: @Ivanhercaz good idea, but the app should be capable of changing the plots data